# UIButton works with one background image, not with another

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIButton being created programmatically with a background image. Here is the code:

```
self.shiftb = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[self.shiftb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.shiftb setTitle:@"sh" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.shiftb.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.shiftb.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
[self.shiftb setFrame:CGRectMake(0*ss.size.width/10, 2*ss.size.height/4, 1.5*ss.size.width/10,ss.size.height/4)];
[self.shiftb addTarget:self action:@selector(shift) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:self.shiftb];
```

As you can see, i'm setting the background image to @"back.png". The above code works perfectly.

if I set it to @"shift1.png" like this:

```
[self.shiftb setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shift1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

When I use this code, the button appears with no background at all. Both images exist, in the same directory, and they are both the same size. Why could this be happening?

Comment: try this [[UIImage imageNamed:@"shift1.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]

Comment: I checked everything: the images are identical except for the name.

Comment: change the button type may be its work [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];